# Unique value numbers in an array or image

Tags: c++, image-processing, stl

I am now reading a image from a disk. The image can be gray scale image or binary image. However, I cannot tell from the header file of the image. What I am now doing is to tell the number of unique pixels. If the unique pixel number is more than two, then the image is gray-scale; otherwise it is black-and-white image. I am using the following function to do the job:

```
  bool is_binary_image(  std::vector<unsigned char> &memory)
{
    std::set<unsigned char> myset;
    for(  std::vector<unsigned char>::iterator  it = memory.begin();
        it!= memory.end(); 
        it++)
    {
        myset.insert(*it);
        if (myset.size()>2)
            return false;
    }

    return true;

}
```

This function can do well if the candidate image is gray-scale image. However, if the candidate image is binary, then the function is time-consuming. Any ideas on improving the function?

Comment: Iterate until you find three distinct values.

Comment: @jrok, is that not what he does?

Comment: Can you rely on values for the binary image to be always the same, e.g. 0xff and 0x00?

Comment: @NeilKirk Hm, actualy it is, my bad :) I'd try to do it without a `set`, though.

Comment: Yes, set does seem overkill if it will only hold 2 useful values. But I'm not convinced it slows it down significantly.

Comment: This algorithm looks like a good candidate for parallelization: partition your input depending on your number of cores, handle each partition in a separate thread, merge the results back. Don't forget to add a common `atomic<bool>` to allow other threads to exit early if one has determined that your image is greyscale.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can speed it up by using array instead of map:

```
bool is_binary_image(  std::vector<unsigned char> &memory)
{
    int counter = 0;
    int pixels[256] = {};

    for(  std::vector<unsigned char>::iterator  it = memory.begin();
        it!= memory.end(); 
        it++)
    {
        pixels[*it]++;
        if (pixels[*it]==1)
          counter++;
        if (counter>2)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**EDIT**

and here is optimized version (but probably less readable), thx TemplateRex:

```
bool is_binary_image(  std::vector<unsigned char> &memory)
{
    int counter = 0;
    int pixels[256] = {};

    for(  std::vector<unsigned char>::iterator  it = memory.begin();
        it!= memory.end(); 
        it++)
    {
        if ((counter += (++pixels[*it] == 1))>2)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: the point being that 256 is the number of values a pixel can take on

Comment: Why such a big array when there won't be more than 2/3 interesting values?

Comment: do you know a priori which ones? there are 256 possible values of unsigned char, and every of them can appear at any moment

Comment: micro-optimization that saves an if and expression evaluation:  `counter += (++pixels[*it] == 1);`

Comment: and btw, you need a `std::array<int, 256>` to have all the counts start at zero, that will not happen with `int pixels[256];`

Comment: If you find 3 unique values you have your result. You don't need to count all possibilities.

Comment: @TemplateRex agree, I forgot to add initialization of array (but I prefer to give compiler more freedom by int pixels[256]= {}; statemant), I have edited the post, thx

Answer (score 1):

Take the first pixel. Then search for the next pixel that is not equal to the first pixel. Now search onwards for a pixel that is neither of the two. If you rearch the end, it is a binary image.

Comment: No, this will not work if you have a grey scale image that has completely white line at the beginning followed by a black line and the something in grey

Comment: This would work, but there is really no need to search backwards - simply continue from the position of the second pixel until the end of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Without making any assumptions about the image, there really is not a whole lot you can do (as far as iterating over the entire image is concerned). In the worst case, the last pixel checked within the image has the third value, so you have to check all pixels to be certain that it is not a gray-scale image.

That said, the way you go about it is fairly inefficient. If you know the possible values of the black-and-white pixels, you could simply iterate through the pixels and check if the value is different than black and white. This would eliminate the set, and should dramatically increase the performance.